# Woocommerce delivery restriction according to specific coupon

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

one coupon i created 'ABC' and i want that if customers select delivery date/day through date picker between Friday To Sunday then coupon not to be work and if customer select other days (Monday to Thursday) then only coupon to be work.
Is it possible? If yes, then how can i achieve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this hook to add custom validation for coupon.

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product', false, $product, $this, $values );
```

Here you will get all the parameters and you can check the days along with coupon code.